# Same channel for different methods

Tags: spring-integration

it is possible to use a multimethod interface as an gateway with just one channel ?

i use spring integration 4.1.2.RELEASE.

The different methods are call different API's methods on other servers.

My config/source looks like:

The Gateway:

```java
@MessagingGateway
public interface TestService
{
  @Gateway(requestChannel="testRequestChannel")
  public Test findTestById( String test );

  @Gateway(requestChannel="testRequestChannel")
  public List<Test> getTests();

  .... many more methods ....
}
```

The Service Impl:

```java
@MessageEndpoint
public class TestServiceImpl
{
  @ServiceActivator( inputChannel = "testRequestChannel")    
  public Test findTestById( String test )
  {
    ...
  }

  @ServiceActivator( inputChannel = "testRequestChannel")    
  public List<Test> getTests( String test )
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

The model:

```java
@Service
public class TestModel
{
  @Autowired
  private TestService testService;

  public Test findTestById( String test )
  {
    return this.testService.findTestById(test);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Marcel

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that; having 2 services subscribed to the same channel means (by default) requests on that channel will be round-robin dispatched to the methods in turn.

Since you are starting your flow with a gateway, why not just use a separate channel for each?

Comment: I've an interface with multiple methods. For me, it sounds horrible to create an channel for every method ...

Are there any other solutions (simple like an gateway) for my problem ?

Comment: You don't have to declare the channels, just give them unuque names. The framework will create default declarations.

Comment: Well, you misunderstood messaging principles a bit. The `channel` is on of first class citizen. And his goal to receive messages from producer and deliver them to the subscriber. Please, read the [(EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/) book for theory. You an do that just only with single channel, but in that case you should place a router on it and use `#gatewayMethod` SpEL variable to populate the message header to be use as a routing key in that router. However you must provide channel in the downstream anyway. Or use single service for all cases. That's how framewrok works!